# Powershell script that extracts medadata from powershell script

Tags: powershell-2.0

Does anybody know of a script or powershell windows utility, or 3rd party utility, codeplex, poshcode script, app, whatever etc, which can read and scan a powershell script and detail what snapins, providers, assemblies, cmdlets, functions, etc, etc, etc, the script needs to execute.

Thanks.
Bob.

Answer (score 2):

First things first: No, I don't know of such a script/utility.

I suspect, though, that you can get pretty far with Powershell's capabilities of parsing itself.

For example, the following script:

```
function test {}

test

$content = gc $args[0]
[System.Management.Automation.PsParser]::Tokenize($content, [ref] $null) |
   ? { $_.Type -eq "Command" } | ft
```

given itself as argument yields the following output:

```
Content                  Type          Start         Length      StartLine    StartColumn        EndLine      EndColumn
-------                  ----          -----         ------      ---------    -----------        -------      ---------
test                  Command             20              4              3              1              3              5
gc                    Command             39              2              5             12              5             14
?                     Command            127              1              6             76              6             77
ft                    Command            157              2              6            106              6            108
```

So, the "Command" type includes at least functions and cmdlets. You can further dissect this by un-aliasing those tokens.

This probably can tell you a little already but comes nowhere close to your pretty exhaustive list of what Powershell scripts *could* require.

But at least in the case of snap-ins or modules you probably need some magic anyway to know precisely *what's* missing.

Comment: The pspaser tokenizer. I'd forgotten about that.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, we make several of these utilities:

http://scriptcop.start-automating.com - Free online / downloadable static analysis of PowerShell scripts
http://scriptcoverage.startautomating.com/ - Code Coverage Tool for Powershell Scripts

There's also a tool in the module [ShowUI](http://showui.com) (Get-ReferencedCommand) that does exactly what you'd want.   It looks at every command used within a command, and every command they use, to produce a list of all commands you must include.

You use it like:  `Get-ReferenedCommand -ScriptBlock { Start-MyCommand }`

Hope this Helps